# Finding a domain of a function

Tags: functions

What would be the best approach finding this function's domain?

$$f (x) = \sqrt{\cfrac{x-2}{x+2}} + \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1+x}}}$$

Can I just calculate the domain of each expression seperately?

$$
\sqrt{\cfrac{x-2}{x+2}}
$$

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1+x}}}
$$

Thanks :)

Comment: You can do that, and then take take the intersection of these two domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the domain of the function is the intersection of the two domains. For a simpler example, think about this expression:
$$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$$
The domain of $x$ is clearly $\mathbb{R}$. The domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is clearly $\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq0$. Thus, the domain of $x + \frac{1}{x}$ is the common subset:  $x \in \mathbb{R} | x\neq 0$.

For your case:
$$D:{\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x+2}}}=\left [ x\in \mathbb{R} | x>-2, x >= 2\right]\rightarrow x>=2$$
$$D:{\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1+x}}}}=\left[x\in \mathbb{R} \right | x >-1 , x <= 1]$$
So the intersection of the sets are:
$$D_{combined}=(2,\infty) \cap (-1,1 ]=\emptyset$$

Comment: The domain of the first term is actually $(-\infty, -2) \cup [2, \infty)$

Comment: Good catch. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can make slight shortcuts by keeping all of it in mind at the same time.

First, for $\sqrt{1+x}$ to be defined and nonzero we need $x>-1$. Since the square root is then positive we must also have $1-x\ge 0$ or in other words $x\le 1$.

On the other hand, when $1+x$ is positive, then $x+2$ is certainly also positive. But if $x\le 1$, the $x-2$ is always *negative* ...